# Hclust using a starting solution

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have run a segmentation on US data. How can I apply the similar cluster assignment (as a starting solution) to other markets? Both US and other markets have the same exact inputs and survey.

Here are my codes:

```
TwoStepCluster <-function(xdata, k, method="ward.D2", factor=FALSE) {
  if (factor==TRUE) {
    xdata=PCA(xdata,k)
  }
  if (method == "mclust") {
    start = Mclust(xdata,4)$classification
    cen   = capply(xdata, start) 
  } else if (method != "none") {
    d  = dist(xdata)
    hcstart = cutree(hclust(d, method = method), k)
    cen = capply(xdata, hcstart) 
  } else {cen=k}
  km = kmeans(xdata, cen, iter.max=100)
  return(as.matrix(km$cluster))
}
```

Are there any options in the hclust or kmeans function to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, k-means accepts starting points.

Look for a "seeds" or "initial centers" option.

As for hclust, you'd probably better cluster all markets at once, then project this to the different markets afterwards.